# Handle exception in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, exception

I called a method `@txt.watch` inside model from worker and Inside `watch()` there is an array of `parameters(parameters = self.parameters)`. Each parameter have unique reference id.
I want to rescue each exception error for each parameter from inside worker.

```
 class TextWorker
    def perform(id)
      @txt = WriteTxt.find(id)
      begin
        @txt.watch
        total_complete_watch = if @txt.job_type == 'movie'
                                @txt.total_count
                              else
                                @txt.tracks.where(status:'complete').size
                              end
        @txt.completed = total_completed_games
        @txt.complete = (total_complete_games == @txt.total_count)
        @txt.completed_at = Time.zone.now if @txt.complete
        @txt.zipper if @txt.complete
        @txt.save
        FileUtils.rm_rf @txt.base_dir if @txt.complete
      rescue StandardError => e
        #How to find errors for each reference_id here
      raise e
      end
    end
  end
```

Is there any way to do. Thanks u very much.

Comment: Exception raise one by one, they aren't collected.

Comment: If `@txt.watch` at any stage throws an error, your code will jump to calling the  `rescue StandardError => e` line.

Can you share the `watch` method?  It might be best to do this in there.

Comment: def watch
       txt = ''
       self.parameters.each do |parameter|
          txt += movie_list(parameter)
       end
       write_list(txt)
   end

Answer (score 1):

I assume `self.parameters` are in your Model class instance.  In that case, do as follows and you can reference them.

```
begin
  @txt.watch
rescue StandardError
  p @parameters  # => self.parameters in the Model context
  raise
end
```

**Note**:

As a rule of thumb, it is recommended to limit the scope of rescue as narrow as possible.  Do not include statements which should not raise Exceptions in your main clause (such as, `@txt.save` and `FileUtils.rm_rf` in your case).  Also, it is far better to limit the class of an exception; for example, rescue `Encoding::CompatibilityError` instead of `EncodingError`, or `EncodingError` instaed of `StandardError`, and so on.  Or, an even better way is to define your own Exception class and raise it deliberately.